# Facing build failure for Apache Solr

Tags: java, apache, solr

I am facing following error while building Apache Solr 7.1.0 using OpenJDK 8

> ```
> [javac] Compiling 1148 source files to /solr-7.1.0/solr/build/solr-core/classes/java
> [javac]
> [javac]
> [javac] The system is out of resources.
> [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
> [javac] java.lang.StackOverflowError
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AssignAnalyzer.scanExpr(Flow.java:1635)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AssignAnalyzer.visitApply(Flow.java:2258)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$BaseAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:404)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AssignAnalyzer.scan(Flow.java:1382)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.visitSelect(TreeScanner.java:264)
> [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow$AssignAnalyzer.visitSelect(Flow.java:2337)
> ```

Increasing the stack size using -Xss option didn't resolve the issue. 
I have tried to even increase the stack size by modifying solr default options. 
But it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Exactly how did you try to increase the stack size? How are you starting the compile process? (you can configure javac settings for ant separately)

Comment: I have used export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xss1g" to increase the stack size.And useing "ant server" command to build the code.